# C#, How to tell if first element of array is null, when array could possibly have no elements?

Tags: c#

This code can throw a null pointer exception.

```
if (myArray[0] != null)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

How can I test to make sure there is an element @ index `0`?
Without throwing an exception when the array is empty.

Comment: First test to see if array is empty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what you need to check, some combination of these conditions:

```
if (myArray != null && myArray.Length > 0 && myArray[0] != null)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One small change I would make to Tim's answer is this:

```
if (myArray != null && myArray.Any() && myArray[0] != null) 
{ 
    //Do Something 
}
```

.Any checks to see if there is at least 1 without having to iterate thru the entire collection. Also, this version works with any IList< T>-implemtor.

I understand that there might be a LINQ/IEnumerable-version of .IsNullOrEmpty in some future version of .NET which would be very handy here. Heck, you could implement it as an extension method yourself!

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return (source == null || !source.Any());
    }
}
```

Then your test becomes

```
if (!myArray.IsNullOrEmpty() && myArray[0] != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Checking the `Length` or `Count` of an array or list (most/all `ICollection`s, really) is an O(1) operation, it does not require iterating through the entire collection.  The LINQ `Any()` method you suggest is slightly slower than checking the `Length` or `Count` yourself, but could be preferable, especially since it works on any `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Tim: You're right. I'm so used to 'assuming' nothing about what is implemmenting the interfaces I'm using. Even if the IEnumerable is really a IList LINQ is smart enough to call .Count rather than iterate. Still, I prefer the generality here.

Comment: Properties should be quick operations.  If it's possible to count an IEnumerable, but takes a while, it should be a `GetCount()` method instead.  Obviously, this isn't always true, but it's an assumption about what a property is, instead of assuming something about an interface.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if *myArray* is null. If it's not, then check it's elements count:

```
if (myArray != null && myArray.Length > 0)
{
   // myArray has at least one element
}
```

If first condition is false, then second will not be checked, so when *myArray* is null no exception will be thrown.